Django e-mail not sending
I've been trying to send a confirmation mail upon registering through the django-email-verification app.
However, despite having no error being shown, no e-mail is received.
My web app is hosted on PythonAnywhere (Paid plan).
I have tried multiple e-mails and multiple debugging. No shots. Here is the code :
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        [...]
        if commit:
            user.save()
            send_email(user)
            user.is_active = False
        return user

The send_email function brings to this :
def send_inner_thread(user, kind, token, expiry, sender, domain, subject, mail_plain, mail_html, debug, context):
    domain += '/' if not domain.endswith('/') else ''

    [...]

    try:
        msg.send()  # Attempt to send the email
        print("Email sent successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending email: {e}")

And here's my console log :
2024-05-31 17:08:48 <django.core.mail.message.EmailMultiAlternatives object at 0x7f78fff17bb0>
2024-05-31 17:08:48 Content-Type: multipart/alternative;#012 boundary="===============XXXXXXXXXX=="#012MIME-Version: 1.0 [... rest of the mails infos ... ]
2024-05-31 17:08:48 Email sent successfully!

Here's my settings.py :
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "MAIL@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'APP PWD'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

Any help is very welcome ! Thanks for reading :)

django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend that backend simply prints the mail out on the console without actually sending anything...
